# Passing a 2D array of Structs by reference in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, function, reference, 2d

SO im pretty new to c++ and im trying to pass a 2D array of a struct type by reference to a function. As far as i know they are automatically passed by reference. Here is my code.The problem is probably obvious but i cant figure it out. The complier keeps saying variable or field "function" declared void and bArray was not declared in this scope.

```
void function(balloons bArray[][5]);

int main()
{
    struct balloons
    {
           float totalWeight;
        float largestBalloon;
    };
      balloons balloonsArray[20][5];

    function(balloonsArray);
} 

void function(balloons bArray[][5])
{
    bArray[1][1].totalWeight = 1.0
    bArray[1][1].largestBalloon = 1.0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're defining your `struct` within `main`, other parts of your code need to use it also. Move the definition outside the function:

```
struct balloons
{
       float totalWeight;
    float largestBalloon;
};

void function(balloons bArray[][5]);

int main()
{
    // ...
```

And you haven't terminated the two statements in your function, you'll need semicolons there:

```
bArray[1][1].totalWeight = 1.0;
bArray[1][1].largestBalloon = 1.0;
```

Comment: After the definition, the name `balloons` is allowed and generally preferred. Note the `C++` tag...

Comment: Ive done the following changes and im still getting proj1.cpp:18: error: variable or field ‘function’ declared void
proj1.cpp:18: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘bArray’
proj1.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
proj1.cpp:30: error: ‘function’ was not declared in this scope

Comment: @BLake: seems like you've messed something up with your function prototype. check again over the part that you changed for problems.

Comment: this is my function prototype void function(balloons bArray[][5]); and im still getting those errors. I think that the compiler is not recognizing that i want to pass an array which is creating the "function declared void" error and is also why it wants a ")" before bArray. So im guessing that my format for my prototype is not correct. Does anyone know what is wrong with it?